# Help With Quadratic equation from data table. No Graph.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a table of data whose OUTPUT values range from 0 to 58.

The input values range from 691 to 521. the gap between 691 and 521 = 170

In a linear relationship as I input numbers from 691 going downward to lower numbers the OUTPUT numbers also decrease from a maximum of 58 at 691 and 0 at the minimum input value of 521.

At input of 621 I am 621 - 521 = 100 above the minimum. Then 100 / 170 = 0.588. I then take 0.588 and multiply by 58 and get 34.11

This is a linear relationship and it is analogous to working out percentages. Linear is easy for me.

The actual data in my table appears to have parabolic data curve. At input of 621 the actual output value is 48. The error is 13.88

At input of 615 the linear calculation output value is 32.07059 but the actual output value is 46. the error is 13.929

At input of 610 the linear calculation output value is 30.367 but the actual output value is 46. the error is 14.635

At input of 606 [this is mid point] the linear calculation output value is 29 but the actual output value is 44. the error is 15

At input of 600 the linear calculation output value is 26.952 but the actual output value is 42. the error is 15.04706

At input of 590 the linear calculation output value is 23.54118 but the actual output value is 38. the error is 14.45882

At input of 570 the linear calculation output value is 16.71765 but the actual output value is 30. the error is 13.28235

At input of 570 the linear calculation output value is 6.4823 but the actual output value is 13. the error is 6.517

As you can see as I approach the input mid point of 606, from either above (going down) OR from below (going up) the error increases and the approximate maximum of the error is 15, which is approx. a quarter of 15.

I can also say that As you input numbers above 621 (going up toward 691) the error from linear calculation decreases to zero.

Also, as you go lower toward 521 the error from linear calculation again decreases to zero.

Also, the error (or deviation) is not linear itself. It seems to me it is curved.

My guess is that I am looking a parabolic graph and I want to learn how to find the quadratic equation for it.

It is not a standard textbook exercise with y and x intercept, although you might impose such coordinates from the numbers in the data table.

Can someone give a  step by step method to find the equations from using the data in the tables. I don't want to draw a graph. I need equations for a computer algorithm.

Comment: Lookup "Least squares method". For a given dataset, you can for instance determine the second degree polynomial that best approximates the data (in the sense of least squares...)

Comment: Phew, that's one long read! You could just post the data and say that you need to find a quadratic polynomial that fits the data ... If I open Excel and try to write all the data, it takes quite a long time to comb through your text.

Comment: This is not very descriptive of your data set. If they are ordered pairs, consider presenting them in a table form and droppig all the vague description.

Comment: So the main takeaway is perhaps this: Notice that in Excel (or any free alternative) has a feature to do exactly this. Please find it and learn to use it. I do it like this: Draw a Scatter graph of the data. When you have the plot, click on any datapoint and select Format Trendline. There you will find the options to carry this out.

Comment: Thanx guy. I'll try better to keep the questions short and more concise.